# How to enable "type information" for streams returned from methods?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream

Since a few versions, IntelliJ has a very helpful feature: when you put the individual method calls of a `stream()` statement on separate lines, IntelliJ puts type information on each line:

[image: with type information]

But when you don't call `stream()` directly, like when it is returned from another method, that information is omitted:

[image: without types]

Is there a way to convince IntelliJ to show such type information for such situations, too?

As pure text, with manually inserted comments to "show" the problem with pure text:

```
public Stream<Entry<String, String>> withTypeInformation() {
    return generateMap() // Map<String, String>
            .entrySet()  // Set<Entry<String, String>>
            .stream()    // Stream<Set<Entry<String, String>>>
            .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals("foo")) // Stream<Set<Entry<String, String>>>
            .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals("bar")) // Stream<Set<Entry<String, String>>>
            .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals("now"));
}

public Stream<Entry<String, String>> withoutTypeInformation() {
    return withTypeInformation() // no such info 
            .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals("foo")) // not here either
            .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals("bar")) // guess what, nothing, too
            .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals("now"));
}
```

And note: the first method uses a generator method that returns a map instance. There IntelliJ is smart enough to give me the type information?!

Comment: Might just be related to the state of the `Stream` (creation or transformation), I tried adding `.map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))` in the `withoutTypeInformation` method and the hints appeared.

Comment: I also get this for stuff other than streams. NB, I believe this is called ["call chain type hints"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-editor-appearance.html).

Comment: @Naman Interesting, yes, that works for me too. But well, that doesn't really help, does it. Adding such a transformation just the fix an IDE issue isn't exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Further to second Andy, it doesn't seem related to stream in particular. For example  `private Stream<Map.Entry<String, String>> withTypeInformation() {
        return Map.of("", "")
                .entrySet()
                .stream();
    }` won't result in any hints at all. versus `private Stream<Map.Entry<String, String>> withTypeInformation() {
        return Map.of("", "")
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals("foo"));
    }` this does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, there is a heuristic, that makes IDEA not show this hints. If the count of different types the single chain is less than 3, they won't be shown. It is required to avoid spamming this hints, when the type of expression is obvious (e. g. builders).

In IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 count of different types, required to show hints can be adjusted in settings (if set it to 1, hints will be always shown).

Note: to get to that setting, one has to turn to Preferences -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Java and change the "unique type count" for "Method hints".

Comment: Settings for hints were introduced in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 EAP (the latest one). You can find them at Editor > Inlay Hints > Java > Method chains.

Comment: I overlooked your comment, and took the freedom to edit your answer accordingly! Thank you very much!