# Identify record that is culprit - coding practices

Tags: java, java-stream

Is method chaining good?

I am not against functional programming that uses method chaining a lot, but against a herd mentality where people mindlessly run behind something that is new.

The example, if I am processing a list of items using stream programming and need to find out the exact row that resulted into throwing `NullPointerException`.

```
private void test() {
    List<User> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    // fill aList with some data
    aList.stream().forEach(x -> doSomethingMeaningFul(x.getAddress()));
}

private void doSomethingMeaningFul(Address x)   {
     // Do something
}
```

So in the example above if any object in list is null, it will lead to `NullPointerException` while calling `x.getAddress()` and come out, without giving us a hook to identify a User record which has this problem.

I may be missing something that offers this feature in stream programming, any help is appreciated.

Edit 1:
NPE is just an example, but there are several other RuntimeExceptions that could occur.  Writing filter would essentially mean checking for every RTE condition based on the operation I am performing.  And checking for every operation will become a pain.

To give a better idea about what I mean following is the snippet using older methods; I couldn't find any equivalent with streams / functional programming methods.

```
List<User> aList = new ArrayList<>();
// Fill list with some data
int counter = 0;
User u = null;

try {
      for (;counter < aList.size(); counter++) {
          u = aList.get(counter);
          u.doSomething();
          int result = u.getX() / u.getY();
      }
} catch(Exception e)  {
  System.out.println("Error processing at index:" + counter + " with User record:" + u);
  System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
}

This will be a boon during the maintenance phase(longest phase) pointing exact data related issues which are difficult to reproduce.
**Benefits:**
- Find exact index causing issue, pointing to data
- Any RTE is recorded and analyzed against the user record
- Smaller stacktrace to look at
```

Comment: You should probably filter out null values first, and do a `map` instead of a `forEach` if you want a bit more functional style -- your `doSomething` would be better off returning the result instead of putting it somewhere hidden.

Comment: How to do it with stream programming is something I am looking for.

Comment: @NitinDubey You are already using `stream` but to no use. Maybe look into `filter(Objects:nonNull)`

Comment: If you just want an index to put in an error object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few aspects to this.

**1) Nulls**

It's best to avoid the problem of checking for nulls, by never assigning null. This applies whether you're doing functional programming or not. Unfortunately a lot of library code does expose the possibility of a null return value, but try to limit exposure to this by handling it in one place.

Regardless of whether you're doing FP or not, you'll find you get a lot less frustrated if you never have to write null checks when calling your own methods, because your own methods can never return null.

An alternative to variables that might be null, is to use Java 8's `Optional` class.

Instead of:

```
public String myMethod(int i) {
     if(i>0) {
          return "Hello";
     } else {
          return null;
     }
}
```

Do:

```
public Optional<String> myMethod(int i) {
     if(i>0) {
          return Optional.of("Hello");
     } else {
          return Optional.empty();
}
```

Look at `Optional` Javadoc to see how this forces the caller to think about the possibility of an `Optional.empty()` response.

As a bridge between the worlds of "null represents absent" and "`Optional.empty()` represents absent", you can use `Optional.ofNullable(val)` which returns `Empty` when `val == null`. But do bear in mind that `Optional.empty()` and `Optional.of(null)` are different values.

**2) Exceptions**

It's true that throwing an exception in a stream handler doesn't work very well. Exceptions aren't a very FP-friendly mechanism. The FP-friendly alternative is `Either` -- which isn't a standard part of Java but is easy to write yourself or find in third party libraries: [Is there an equivalent of Scala's Either in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162407/is-there-an-equivalent-of-scalas-either-in-java-8)

```
public Either<Exception, Result> meaningfulMethod(Value val) {
    try {
       return Either.right(methodThatMightThrow(val));
    } catch (Exception e) {
       return Either.left(e);
    }
}
```

... then:

```
List<Either<Exception, Result>> results = listOfValues.stream().map(meaningfulMethod).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**3) Indexes**

You want to know the index of the stream element, when you're using a stream made from a `List`? See [Is there a concise way to iterate over a stream with indices in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8)

Answer (score 1):

> Is method chaining good?

As so often, the simple answer is: it depends.

When you

- know what you are doing
- are be *very* sure that elements will never be null, thus the chance for an NPE in such a construct is (close to) 0
- **and** the chaining of calls leads to improved readability

then sure, chain calls.

If any of the above criteria isn't clearly fulfilled, then consider not doing that.

In any case, it might be helpful to distribute your method calls on new lines. Tools like IntelliJ actually give you advanced type information for each line, when you do that (well, not always, see  my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489184/how-to-enable-type-information-for-streams-returned-from-methods) ;)

From a different perspective: to the compiler, it doesn't matter much if you chain call. That really only matters to humans. Either for readability, or during debugging.

Comment: Yes I agree, every method call should be new line to identify such item in stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In your test() function you are creating an emptylist  `List<User> aList = new ArrayList<>();`

And doing for each on it. First add some element to

> aList

If you want to handle null values you can add `.filter(x-> x != null)` this before foreach it will filter out all null value

**Below is code**

```
private void test() {
        List<User> aList = new ArrayList<>();

        aList.stream().filter(x-> x != null).forEach(x -> doSomethingMeaningFul(x.getAddress()));
}

private void doSomethingMeaningFul(Address x)   {
        // Do something
}
```

Comment: That means we would be processing the list twice, so it will have performance impact.

Comment: Why call forEach() on a stream, and not map?

Comment: @NitinDubey first you are filtering null from lis then you are doing processing

Comment: @NitinDubey If you donot want to filter null values then add if condition inside your forEach and first check if(x != null) then call your function doSomethingMeaningFul(x.getAddress)

Comment: @NitinDubey no, this does not process the list twice. You wrap the list in a stream. `forEach()` pulls an item from `filter()`. `filter()` pulls items from the stream and only yields an element to `forEach()` if it passes the predicate.

Comment: @slim got it thanks.  I have edited the question to bring more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a black of code in streams. And you can find out the list item which might result in **NullPointerException**. I hope this code might help

```
private void test() {
    List<User> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    aList.stream().forEach(x -> {
        if(x.getAddress() != null)
            return doSomethingMeaningFul(x.getAddress())
        else
            system.out.println(x+ "doesn't have address");
    });
}

private void doSomethingMeaningFul(Address x)   {
 // Do something
}
```

If you want you can throw **NullPointerException** or custom excption like **AddressNotFoundException** in the ***else*** part